# Redirect links from old to new domain as I browse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, greasemonkey, redirect

So my use case is something like this -

We used to access JIRA site with an old domain:

```
https://domain1/browse/TKT-12100
```

Now the domain is moved to:

```
https://domain2/browse/TKT-12100
```

But my browser history has all links with domain1. I usually type a few keywords in my browser URL tab and auto complete and enter. Now at this point I want to dynamically replace domain1 with domain2 so that my JIRA tickets load fine. I hate the manual step here.

I am looking for something on lines of Greasemonkey script to achieve this but any other methods are also welcome.

Comment: Could you add a rewrite rule to the server?  With a 301?

Comment: Old server is decommissioned and is no longer available.

Comment: Is updating the DNS to point to the new server an option?

Comment: Well it can be but this is something that is very specific to me and I don think we can do an organization wide DNA change just for this. I want to do something that is specific and bound to my local.

Comment: Perhaps /etc/hosts?

Comment: @user2182349 not sure how that would work. I don't have the IP of https://domain1 as it no longer exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how it finally worked for me. Apparently grease monkey scripts do not work if the server is not live. So first I changed /etc/hosts file to -

```
IPOfDomain2 domain1 domain2
```

Post this change GM script is working fine - https://gist.github.com/aniket91/464ed8f61ecdeec7cf99ae65ea6514c9

Comment: I recommend that you use `window.location.replace` in your script as recommended in Brock Adams' deleted answer.

Comment: @TomášZato does it have any benefits over `window.location.href = currentUrl;`?

Comment: Quoting Brock Adams: "*replace() puts the good page in the history instead of the bad page.*". Generally IMHO his code is better than yours. I did not realize you cannot see that answer anymore. I'll copy it for you.

Comment: @TomášZato thanks. I do see the deleted answer but did not notice the comment there. Updated my code in the gist.